# Can one say both Meshaneh Habriyot as well as Shekacha .. B'olamo for the same creature, sequentially?

Tags: blessing

ברוך...שככה לו בעולמו is said upon seeing beautiful trees or creatures (animals or people).

O.C. 228 says (translation copied from [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105433/5275)

> for seeing a person with a dark, very red, or albino white complexion-
>   or a person who is bent over because of obesity, a midget, a person
>   with a lot of warts, a person with hair that clings to each other, a
>   mentally incompetent person, an person missing a limb, a blind person,
>   a person with boils

If someone sees a beautiful midget woman or man, should s/he make both brachot? Is there any order to say them?

Comment: To answer that we should really understand the intention of both, which we seemingly don't. But wait, can one say both הטוה והמיטיב and דיין האמת on the same news? IIRC yes.

Comment: @AlBerko I think O.C. explicitly mentions that if your father died and left you a huge inheritance, you would say both.

Comment: So I don't know if we can learn one from another. The problem with all the Brochos, is that we don't really know how they work - this Rabbi proposes this Brocho and another Rabbi something different without explaining why and how. My other question aimed exactly that but its negative acceptance just showed how little people care about טעמי המצוות.

Comment: @AlBerko No one really completely understands why or how people vote on this site. Browse a bit and you'll see many questions with high votes but not one answer. And, some with multiple answers and zero or negative scores.